# google map v3 for flash sdk 3.5

Tags: flash, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a flash based site using SDK 3.5.0 and the Google Map Flash API.  Google sent me an email today say that since it uses version 2.0 of their API it will stop functioning on September 2nd.

I have been working on a new version of the site using HTML 5 but it will not be done in time so I have a problem.

Can anyone make any suggest for a replacement for the Google Map Flash API or a link to instructions on using the Google Map API V3 in flash.  I know how to use them in JavaScript but Flash is not a language I am use to using much.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. you may wanna take a look on the Bing API.

I've found this guy talking about how to use it as a replacement for the Gmaps: 
http://krpano.com/forum/wbb/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=6906

The thing is, you'll have to re-code anyways, so... maybe you should just use javascript. I don't know how complex is your map, but the Google Maps' documentation is pretty solid and you can always take a look here and ask more info if you get stuck.

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the link to openscales.org I will look into that possibility.  It does seem no matter what I do I have a mess on my hands.  As I stated in the original question, I am working on a javascript version it just won't be ready in time.

Comment: looks like the http://krpano.com will require a rewrite of the whole site.  They are not a replacement for the Google Map Flash API that I can find.